# How to isolate a process so that it can only see one network interface?

Tags: networking

Is there a way to make only one specific network interface (e.g. eth3) available to a process so that no other interfaces are visible?

Comment: Related: [How can an application (like Firefox) be forced to use a certain network interface?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25778/how-can-an-application-like-firefox-be-forced-to-use-a-certain-network-interfac)

Answer (score 1):

There is a unix saying *everything is a file*. If your program gets filesystem access, it can at least see all devices (if access rights are set so, which they probably are).

The easy solution could be virtualization, like using [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) or [User Mode Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Mode_Linux).

Answer (score 0):

In the last years firejail way gain a popularity.

Example:
firejail --net=eth0 firefox

which means limit firefox to eth0 interface.

Website and github link with firegail source code:
https://firejail.wordpress.com/
https://github.com/netblue30/firejail

In my ubuntu 22.04 I can install with just
sudo apt install firejail

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).